# Execute scripts under a different user context in vRealize Automation 7.2

Tags: vmware

I am building blueprints in vRealize Automation 7.2 and I need to be able to execute code from a remote location as part of the process.  I know I can use encrypted properties to provide the credentials of a user and then execute scripts in a different user context, but is that my only option?  I see in vRealize Orchestrator that I can change the credential of the user executing a workflow, but I'm not sure that's my best option either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by mapping a drive on the deployed machine to the network location using powershell scripts.

```
$driveLetter = "U"
$networkPath = "\\network\share"
$userName = "domain\username"
$password = "password"

$psDrive = Get-PSDrive -Name $driveLetter
if ($psDrive)
{
    Remove-PSDrive $psDrive
}
$token = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $token -ErrorAction Stop
$output = New-PSDrive -Name $driveLetter -Root $networkPath -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $credentials -Persist -Scope Global

$driveLetter = $output.Name + ":"
```

I was then able to map the resulting drive letter to other steps install location using vRealize Automation software components and binding the properties to this component's property by marking the property's Binding box checked and setting the Value to ConnectionStep_1~driveLetter property.